# JFace: Resizable tooltip with ColumnViewerToolTipSupport

Tags: eclipse, swt, tooltip, jface

Can anyone show me how to use `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewerToolTipSupport` to create a tooltip similar to the one shown in Eclipse IDE when you hover your mouse to any Java element?  That is, I want the tooltip to be resizable, I also want to hook an F2 key to show the tooltip on demand in addition to mouse hover.

I have managed to add my own custom control to the tooltip (a `TableViewer`), but I can't see any methods/ways to set the tooltip to be resizable and only dissappear when user clicks on a key (e.g. esc key).  Is this even possible with `ColumnViewerToolTipSupport`?

I have used as my reference an example at http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet037FancyCustomTooltips.java?view=markup

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The window appearing in Eclipse when you hover mouse pointer over a Java element is not a tooltip, but [InformationControl](http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/jface-tooltips-via-information-controls100.html). See [org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.install(Control)](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/eclipse/jface/text/AbstractInformationControlManager.java.html) for more information.
I don't think it will work right away with table cells, so you probably will have to combine some [ColumnViewerToolTipSupport](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FColumnViewerToolTipSupport.html) techniques with it.

Cheers,
Max